# Detect when I'm leaving a frame in ActionsScript 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs3

Is there an event listener to use to detect whenever I am leaving a particular frame on my timeline?

If I am correct, Event.FRAME_EXIT only works on the newer versions of Flash. Is that correct? (I am working with CS3.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event.EXIT_FRAME is supported in Flash Player 9 and above:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#EXIT_FRAME

Edit: ... but that doesn't seem to be the whole truth, see comments below.

Comment: But I'm using CS3 and I get a warning that EXIt_FRAME is possibly undefined.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right, I just tested it in CS3 and it didn't compile. And if I set CS4 to publish for Flash Player 9 i get the "access of possibly undefined property EXIT_FRAME" message there also. But if I bypass the EXIT_FRAME constant and do addEventListener("exitFrame", foo), the event fires, so it is there, but the compiler won't let it through. Also, some googling points to that it should only be officially supported in Flash Player 10.